# why image border is set to inline block

Tags: html, css

I added a span element as my circular border to my image which is placed inside a span tag. I noticed that the span tag is pushed down, and giving span a display:inline-block solves it by is it so?

```
 <span class="avatar"><img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt=""></span>
```

Comment: because span is an inline element and its height is defined only by the line-height

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add border radius to your image, yes, span element
have got display inline-block and this property stops your circular border.
Add class or style with border radius inside img tag:

```
<img src="images/avatar.jpg" style="border-radius:35px;"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="avatar"><img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt=""></span>
```

Solution :

```
.avatar{
  border-radius:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```